# Is it allowed to travel within US, having expired visa and valid DS2019?

Tags: visas, domestic-travel, visa-expiration

I am an Indian Research Scholar. I am on a J1 visa and it was valid for 1 year. But my job got extended for another year. Now, my visa got expired, but I got a new DS2019, in which my program ends in August 2023. With an expired visa and valid DS2019, Am I Allowed to travel within the US?

Comment: @littleadv the answers to the proposed duplicate assume that the traveler is out of status .  There's not enough information in that question to know whether that was the case.  But in this case the traveler is in status, so the answers to that question contain a good deal of inapplicable information.

Comment: @littleadv I found a better duplicate.

Comment: Also see [Can I fly within the US if I have a foreign passport with expired visa? Green Card should arrive soon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104743/19400), which isn't directly relevant because of the green card, but has some information about the kinds of controls you might encounter.